# How am I able to intercept server client requests using Chrome and Python?

Tags: python, json, google-chrome

I am trying to intercept data sent from the server to a client , where the script is json and server is nginx (https). Taking for example I am also a client and I am penetration testing the server for vulnerabilities.
I have tried inspecting elements from chrome and everything seems fine (the data is only sent to the other client), I have checked the network files and found nothing, I also tried python import request method, and I have recieved the HTTP 4xx error.

My question is here, what way is there to be able to intercept the data without complete access to server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look for it on the 'Network' or 'Console' tab specifically at the element inspector?
Please note that JSon is not tecnically a script, it is just a object notation, a way of sending information from one place to another, wheareas scripts are intended for interpretation and execution (Bash, JavaScript and Python are examples)

If that data is not being desplayed there, you will probably need some kind of network sniffer (Like wireshark) and filter information comming form that server to your computer. It might be encrypted though, and undreadable for humans.
Hope I helped.

Comment: The client reads this information therefor it is more likely not encrypted. I have searched extensively in the network tab and unfortunately did not find it since the request sent to client is random every time. Thankyou for answering and i will check wireshark, but can it sniff https servers?

Comment: You will be using it to sniff your own network while doing the testing, so it will pickup on all your network trafic, however you can filter all that information by IP/MAC of origin, message types and so one, a quick basic tutorial will show you enough to be able to use it. Good luck